# Control which frontend session/kernel the Workbench gets attached to

Tags: workbench

(I am new to Workbench)

I have 2 or 3 Mathematica frontend sessions open with a few of them running some long-running codes.

When I try to open/edit a code in Workbench, I see that it sometimes it attaches itself to the "busy" frontends. (This is not useful since any new evaluations are queued up)

- How does Workbench interact with Mathematica to decide which frontend to attach to?
- Is there a way in the settings, to force the Workbench to open its "own" new kernel for each session and keep reusing it?
- Is there a way to force the Workbench to open the code (and hence attach to) in a particular frontend session, which is free, so that I can continue coding/debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the WB menus:
Window/Preferences/Mathematica.

You are presented with a dialog where you can select the MMA installation that you want to connect with WB. 
This is all you can do regarding the link between WB and MMA as far as 
I know.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: For this answer to be useful, it needs to give details on how the mentioned dialog is to used.

Comment: @magma Thanks. Those options are for specifying the MMA location - not to specify which instance to attach to

Comment: @myaccount_ram I know, I do not think what you ask is doable though

Comment: @magma : thanks for following up. I find that I sometimes (I do some "tricks") and "attach" to the second MMA session from the Workbench, when the first is crunching some numbers. If it becomes reproducible, I will put them here